# How to use mongoose findAndUpdateOne()

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mern

i am trying to update mongoDB via mongoose using the findOneAndUpdate() method,
i destructure my fields from req.body but if i updated only a single value others are set to null, how do i fix that

---

CODE

```
  const { name, email, phone, type } = req.body;

  await Contact.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: req.params.id },
    { $set: { name, email, type, phone } },
    { upsert: true },
    (err, updatedContact) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
        res.status(400).send('Could not updat');
      } else {
        res.json(updatedContact);
      }
    }
  );
  
});
******************************************
```

Comment: can you clarify what you are asking?

Comment: how to use findOneandUpdate without setting the values you did not want to update to null

Comment: already found a solution thou thanks appreciate ya effort

Answer (score 0):

This gives me the desirable result i expected please not that i have not implemented error checking you can do that using the 'express-validator'

```
  const errors = validationResult(req);
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
  }
  const { name, email, phone, type } = req.body;
  // Build contact object
  const updatedContact = {};
  if (name) updatedContact.name = name;
  if (email) updatedContact.email = email;
  if (phone) updatedContact.phone = phone;
  if (type) updatedContact.type = type;

  try {
    await Contact.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: req.params.id },
      { $set: updatedContact },
      { new: true }
    );

    res.json(updatedContact);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(400).send('Could not update');
  }
});
```